# Databricks access from Azure Container Registry

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using Airflow's DatabricksSubmitRunOperator to run the pyspark code in databricks. I am wondering if I follow the efficient approach or do I need to update the approach that I follow?

1. Separate images for separate processes - let's say in finance, separate image for customers import, and separate image for payment processing. Multiple entry points for multiple clients.
2. Once I have the image in acr, I will run the airflow - databricks operator to run with respective entry points based on client requirements.

But my question is that if I need to create a cluster every time, will it take more time? Do I have any work arounds for this process.

To add this context, data we load is batches. It is in 10's GB, and we will have upto 20 files at maximum.

We will store the bronze layer data (without any processing) into SQL server and gold layer into SQL server as well.

And another question, if at all possible, how should I make it restartable. BTW Source code uses pyspark as functions and classes.

Comment: Why do you need a custom image?

Comment: There is no particular need to have separate image. But it makes more organized dividing different process. I really appreciate any inputs on this. If you think, we can have a single image makes more than separate image, I am good with that approach as well. I only need it to be more efficient and streamlined. I am still in R and D. So any idea that can make the process streamlined, I can try to implement it and analyze the results.

Comment: But if you are asking about why do we need the image itself, it is some organization policy in order to maintain the git, and to avoid having the source code. I understand we can get to source code in acr. But they are okay with this approach but not the in notebooks.

Comment: Docker Container Services on Databricks are necessary in a very limited set of cases, typically people deploy code directly as jars/wheels/... Involve somebody from Databricks for guidance

Comment: I am the first person working on databricks now. Do you mean involving people from Databricks support team?

Comment: Not support, but account team, like solutions architect